# sed inside tcsh foreach loop

Tags: sed, tcsh

```
> foreach i ( `cat /home/chandran/scratch_r/review/1810a042/list2test` )
foreach? sed -i "/^$i /s/$/ ASAN ASAN_CUI/" testify.list
foreach? end
Illegal variable name.
```

Comment: how to use sed inside foreach loop?

Comment: Click the [edit] link if you want to edit/improve your question

Comment: Could you use some words in your question that describe what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
> echo "$/"
Illegal variable name.
> echo '$/'
$/
> set i=blah
> echo "$i"'$/'
blah$/
> echo $i:q'$/'
blah$/
```

So:

```
sed -i '/^'$i:q' /s/$/ ASAN ASAN_CUI/' testify.list
```

Or use a shell with a cleaner/better/easier syntax like `zsh`:

```
zsh% for i ($(< ~/scratch_r/review/1810a042/list2test))
for>   sed -i "/^$i /s/$/ ASAN ASAN_CUI/" testify.list
```

Though here instead of rewriting the `testify.list` over and over, you could do it in one go:

```
sed -i "$(
    sed 's|.*|/^& /s/$/ ASAN ASAN_CUI/|' ~/scratch_r/review/1810a042/list2test
  )" testify.list
```

Or maybe:

```
perl -lapi -e 'BEGIN{while (<STDIN>) {chomp; $w{$_}++}}
               $_ .= " ASAN ASAN_CUI" if $w{$F[0]}
              ' testify.list < ~/scratch_r/review/1810a042/list2test
```

(none tested).

All those assuming the `list2test` contains one word per line, no blank, no `/`, no wildcards or regex operators...